# Calculating length contraction at speed $c$ (not near it)

Tags: special-relativity, length-contraction

Is the Lorentz transform applicable to speeds that are lower than light only?Because I'm trying to calculate length contraction of objects moving at speed $c$ (not near it) and it turns always 0. Is my calculation correct?Please help I'm just a beginner

Suppose a 5 m object is traveling at $c$,so
$$        x'=x/γ$$

\begin{align}
x&=x'\sqrt{(1- (v^2)⁄(c^2)}\\
x&=5\sqrt{1-1}\\
x&=5\sqrt0\\
x&=0
\end{align}
Not infinite right?
If so then the rule will have no length?

Answer (score 6):

This is a case of applying a result outside of the context in which it was validly derived.

The [Lorentz transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_transformation) *does not exist* for relative speed $v = c$.

Recall that the Lorentz transformation relates the *coordinates* in one inertial coordinate system to another uniformly (relatively) moving inertial coordinate system.

In the transformation, there is a [Lorentz factor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_factor)

$$\gamma_v = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 - \frac{v^2}{c^2}}}$$

but $\gamma_c$ does not exist since the denominator vanishes for $v = c$ and division by zero is *undefined*.

Intuitively, we 'know' that one is at rest with respect to one's self (a ruler is not moving with respect to itself).

However, according to the Lorentz transformations, *an object with speed $c$ in one inertial reference frame has speed $c$ in all inertial reference frames*.

Thus, a ruler with speed $c$ in one inertial reference frame has speed $c$ in *all* inertial reference frames.

In other words, there is *no* inertial reference frame in which such a ruler is at rest.

So, it isn't meaningful to think about length contraction in this way.  The formula for length contraction in your question assumes that the ruler has length $L$ *in the inertial reference frame in which it is at rest* but *there is no $L$ to speak of* since there is no inertial reference frame in which the ruler is at rest.

Answer (score 0):

> "1. Is the Lorentz transform applicable to speeds that are lower than light only? -- 2. Because I'm trying to calculate length contraction of objects moving at speed c (not near it) and it turns always 0.".

1. Yes.
2. Moving **any** object with mass would require **infinite** energy (not available) to move it at the speed of light. Even moving a proton (very light weight) would require infinite energy to move at light speed (and an enormous amount of energy to move **almost** that fast).

   Light (a photon) has no weight and moves **only** at the speed of light.

   Light moving, or an observer moving relative to the source, does not alter the mass (or weight) of light but does alter the frequency.

Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Length_contraction#Geometrical_considerations

Answer (score -3):

You're right. 
If you could move at the speed of light, you would not see any length: every object would have zero length; this is called the "length contraction" and it is one of the two phenomena caused by traveling at the speed of light. The other is the time dilatation.